# Compose navigation - replace starting route and clear back stack

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack-navigation

I'm using JetPack Compose with composable NavHost.

I have a scenario where I need a Launch screen that connects bluetooth device so I've set it as my starting route in NavHost.

After connection is done I want to enter Home screen and never get back to that Launch screen.

So after connection is done Launch screen I'm doing this:

```kotlin
   navController.graph.setStartDestination(newHomeRoute)
   navController.navigate(newHomeRoute) {
      popUpTo(0)
      launchSingleTop = true
   }
```

That doesn't work as I get a constant loop going back to LaunchScreen and forward to Home.

So maybe I should do this in some other way?

Answer (score 8):

I had this exact problem.

Sharing my code here.

**SHORT ANSWER**,

```
navHostController.popBackStack("routeOfLaunchingScreen", true)
navHostController.navigate("newHomeRoute")
```

The `true` denotes that pop back stack till and including the given route.
Once the back stack is popped as required, we navigate to the new screen.

Hope this solves your issue. :)

**LONG ANSWER** (copy-paste solution)

**MyNavActions**.

```
class MyNavActions(navHostController: NavHostController) {
    val navigateTo = { navBackStackEntry: NavBackStackEntry, route: String ->
        if (navBackStackEntry.lifecycleIsResumed()) {
            navHostController.navigate(route)
        }
    }

    val navigateUp = { navBackStackEntry: NavBackStackEntry ->
        if (navBackStackEntry.lifecycleIsResumed()) {
            navHostController.navigateUp()
        }
    }

    val popBackStackAndNavigate =
        { navBackStackEntry: NavBackStackEntry, route: String?, popUpTo: String, inclusive: Boolean ->
            if (navBackStackEntry.lifecycleIsResumed()) {
                navHostController.popBackStack(popUpTo, inclusive)
                route?.let {
                    navHostController.navigate(route)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

/**
 * If the lifecycle is not resumed it means this NavBackStackEntry already processed a nav event.
 *
 * This is used to de-duplicate navigation events.
 */
private fun NavBackStackEntry.lifecycleIsResumed() =
    this.lifecycle.currentState == Lifecycle.State.RESUMED
```

**Usage**

```
val myNavActions = remember(navHostController) {
    MyNavActions(navHostController)
}
```

**Pop back stack till given route and navigate**

```
chcNavActions.popBackStackAndNavigate(
    navBackStackEntry,
    routeToPopUpTo,
    routeToNavigateTo,
    true, // inclusive flag - boolean denoting if the specified route `routeToPopUpTo` should also be popped
)
```

**Back Navigation**

```
chcNavActions.navigateUp(navBackStackEntry)
```

**Simple navigation**

```
chcNavActions.navigateTo(navBackStackEntry, route)
```

Comment: Thank you for this long answer. You can check mine, how I actually managed to fix it.

Answer (score 7):

I managed to do this with extension like this:

```kotlin
fun NavHostController.navigateAndReplaceStartRoute(newHomeRoute: String) {
    popBackStack(graph.startDestinationId, true)
    graph.setStartDestination(newHomeRoute)
    navigate(newHomeRoute)
}
```

Comment: If anyone else gets a bouncing issue where it infinitely alternates between start destination and replaced destination, removing the `setStartDestination`, as with @abhimanyu 's short answer, might suit you better

Comment: Hi @Jarrod, you want to say that we just need to replace setStartDestination with Abhimanyu's short answer which is 2 lines of code?

Comment: Unfortunately, this doesn't seem to work for me. I'm using accompanist version 0.23.1. I see constant blinking

Answer (score 7):

You can use this extension:

```
fun NavHostController.navigateAndClean(route: String) {
    navigate(route = route) {
        popUpTo(graph.startDestinationId) { inclusive = true }
    }
    graph.setStartDestination(route)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me

```
navController.navigate(
            route = "new_destination", navOptions = NavOptions.Builder()
                .setPopUpTo("new_destination", inclusive = true)
                .build()
        )
```